# Удалить содержимое элемента без удаления обработчика событий

Tags: jquery, события

Приветствую!

Вопрос задаю впервые. Раньше все ответы находил на форумах. А тут такая штука:

в `jq` есть метод `.empty()`, который удаляет все дочерние блоки из каждого элемента в наборе совпавших элементов, а так же, начиная с версии 1.2.2 эта функция удаляет все обработчики событий!!! и внутренние закешированные данные.

Я использую `.empty()` следующим образом:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",url: "http://xxx.php", 
    data: "art="+art, 
    success: function(html){
        $('form[id=' + art + ']').empty(); 
        $('form[id=' + art + ']').append(html);
    }
});
```

Файл "xxx.php" выводит то же содержимое, которое и было, но с обновлёнными цифрами (пересчет количества товара в корзине).
Проблема в том, что после первого нажатия удаляется не только содержимое, но и обработчик события (в данном случае - клик). И выходит так, что нажимая второй раз, я не получаю нужного результата от моего кода (страница просто перезагружается).

Вопрос: что надо добавить в код, чтоб метод `.empty()` не удалял обработчик событий?

Comment: @lommusic, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку **{}** редактора.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > If you want to remove elements without destroying their data or event handlers (so they can be re-added later), use [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead.

надо  продолжать хранить удаленные элементы в родительском поле видимости (например в массиве) и обновлять их циклом.

иначе вешайте обработчик событий, используйя `.on` в виде

```
$('form').on('event','elementselector',handler);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/BKgVN/

Comment: ребятки, кто поможет непосредственно с кодом поработать? Отблагодарю...

Comment: в смысле за вас код написать ? 

*у меня появляется идея закрыть вопрос*

Comment: нет, показать в чём ошибка и объяснить причину

Comment: так вы код устанавливающий хэндлеры не предоставили. ajax тут непричем. смотрите мой fiddle, он покрывает все вопросы на эту тему.

Answer (score 2):

А не проще сразу сделать?

```
$('form[id=' + art + ']').html(html);
```

еще такой вариант -

```
$(document).on('click','element',function(){
    //some code
})
```

Comment: Попробовал - всё так же как и было. Возможно проблема в другом???

Comment: Привязано правильно, так что в другом, ковыряйте код

Answer (score -1):

Если у тебя обработчики событий повешаны так:

```
$(".element").click(function(){ /* some code... */});
```

То используй метод .on().

```
$(".element").on('click', function(){ /* some code... */});
```

Таким макаром обработчики будут висеть постоянно, даже после пересоздания данного элемента.

Comment: неправда, `on` должен быть на родителе, это не замена `live`

Comment: исправил код, несколько раз всё проверил - тот же результат =(
могу дать ссылку страницу

Comment: кстати, если есть метод в jq который перезагружает один элемент без перезагрузки страницы, то это было бы лучшим решением!!!