# Непонятная ошибка

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Месяц назад я задавал вопрос по своему коду, перепробовал всё что было в ответах - не помогло ничего =(

Проблема в том, что по первому клику на кнопку .kolvomaxcss всё работает шикарно! Но по нажатию на неё второй раз - страница перезагружается и количество не пересчитывается.

Прошу помочь разобраться в чём проблема!!! Поскольку сам реально не понимаю в чём беда, прилагаю подробные исходники.

Скрипт из head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".kolvomaxcss").click(function() {
        var art = $(this).closest('.form_class').attr('id'); // задаём переменную
        if(art) { // если переменная существует
            $.ajax({ // выполняем ajax запрос
                type: "POST", // передача переменной методом POST
                url: "http://xxx.ru/kolvoplus.php", // файл - обработчик
                data: "art="+art, // передаём переменную 
                success: function(html){ // запустится после получения результатов
                    $('form[id=' + art + ']').empty(); // очищаем содержимое
                    $('form[id=' + art + ']').html(html); // выводим содержимое файла "kolvoplus.php"
              }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

php вывод на странице:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['zakaz'])) { // если в сесии есть переменная "zakaz" 
    foreach($_SESSION['zakaz'] as $val1) { // перебираем массив заказа $_SESSION['zakaz'] в массив товара $val1
        $counter = 0; // счетчик
        foreach($val1 as $val) { // перебираем массив товара $val1 в переменные $val
            $counter++;
            if($counter == 1) {$art = $val; // если элемент первый, то это артикул
            }
            if($counter == 2) {$kolvo = $val;} // если элемент второй, то это количество
            }
             echo "
<form class='form_car_update' id='".$art."'>
    <div id='car_echo'>
        <p>кол-во: (гр.)<br>
            <input class='kolvomincss' name='kolvomin' type='submit' value='-' />
            <input name='kolvo' class='kolvo' size=3 type='text' value='".$kolvo."' />
            <input class='kolvomaxcss' name='kolvomax' type='submit' value='+' /><br>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
            ";
        }
    }
?>
```

файл "kolvoplus.php":

```
<?php
session_start();
$art = $_POST['art'];
$_SESSION['zakaz'][$art]['kolvo'] = $_SESSION['zakaz'][$art]['kolvo'] + 50; // увеличиваем количество на 50
$kolvo1 = $_SESSION['zakaz'][$art]['kolvo'];
echo "                  
    <div id='car_echo'>
        <p>кол-во: (гр.)<br>
            <input class='kolvomincss' name='kolvomin' type='submit' value='-' />
            <input name='kolvo' class='kolvo' size=3 type='text' value='".$kolvo."' />
            <input class='kolvomaxcss' name='kolvomax' type='submit' value='+' /><br>
        </p>
    </div>
";
?>
```

Comment: ссылка на вопрос в прошлом месяце -  http://hashcode.ru/questions/242042/jquery-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9?answer_sort=votes

Comment: Кнопка в форме находится?

Comment: Насколько я помню click работает только для существующих элементов на странице, поэтому при добавлении новых input c классом kolvomaxcss они не определяются. Возможно, Вам необходимо использовать функцию live(), или если у Вас версия JQuery > 1.7, тогда $(document).on("click", ".kolvomaxcss", function(event){});

Comment: Кнопка находится в форме, вот тут: 
<input class='kolvomaxcss' name='kolvomax' type='submit' value='+' />

Comment: idd, jQ > 1.7.
Видимо, я имею проблемы с синтаксисом и не понимаю, где должен находиться мой код скрипта в Вашем случае. Я правильно понимаю что это должно выглядеть вот так вот: 

$(document).on("click", ".kolvomaxcss", function(){
здесь код моего скрипта с 3-й по 18-ю стоку
});

?

Comment: с  var art=$(this).... по ...return false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Месяц назад, вам был дан [исчерпывающий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/242042/jquery-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9#242093) и вы за мессяц, не смогли написать это:

```
$(document).on("click", ".kolvomaxcss", function() {
    // бла-бла-бла
});

// или
$(document).delegate(".kolvomaxcss", "click", function() {
});
```

Comment: Я писал это и месяц назад и сейчас проверил ещё раз. 
Пишу: 
$(document).on("click", ".kolvomaxcss", function() {
// здесь код моего скрипта с 3-й по 18-ю стоку
});
Кнопка не работает вообще, при нажатии страница перезагружается...

Comment: Я не знаю каким местом вы пишите (без обид), но — http://jsfiddle.net/E8n6g/

Comment: Спасибо, благодаря Вашему фидлу я разобрался в ситуации!!!

Answer (score 0):

Вы же в обработчике запроса "success" удаляете форму с элементами, на которых висели обработчики событий.

Поэтому ваш код и выполняется только один раз, т.к. после первого ответа на ваш запрос вы перезаписываете все элементы(ваши кнопки в том числе).

Есть два выхода из этой ситуации:

1. Вы после того как получаете новую форму заново вешаете обработчик события на кнопки.
2. Вы не перезаписываете всю форму, а обновляете только нужный вам `input`. Как-то так

   ```
   $('form[id=' + art + '] input.kolvo').val({новое значение});
   ```

Comment: Да, я понял ошибку, вы правы!